# How to min-height a floated DIV?

Tags: css, xhtml, html

I am trying to set a `min-height` to a floated DIV in a XHTML or HTML document.
The fix of putting a fixed-height DIV into the DIV and clearing it with `:after` doesn't work at all. Directly assigning a `min-height` won't work either.

My code as it's now is like (which only works on Firefox in quirks mode but I want it to be something real):

```
<div style="float:left">
 <div style="float:left; height:200px"><!-- min-height hackfix --></div>
 CONTENT GOES HERE
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have an example online?

Comment: Sadly not. Put it in a file w/ proper HTML or XHTML setup (with full Doctype) to see how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't really get what you want, but here is the fix for min-height issue:

```
selector {
  min-height:500px;
  height:auto !important;
  height:500px;
}
```

So, your code can be like this

```
<div style="float:left;min-height:200px;height:auto !important;height:200px;">
     CONTENT GOES HERE
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/pcpsS/1/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, sadly it doesnt change anything.

Comment: Updated my answer. Is it what you want to achieve?

Comment: Still doesnt fix. The div doesn't expand.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast, you mustn't be implementing it properly, you don't need a nested div for this hack, just apply it straight to the inner content floated div - see @YNhat's [fiddle with content added](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/pcpsS/5/) it's expanding just fine for me (change the line-height value between 1 & 5 to test)

Comment: Yes its expanding fine on jsfiddle because it's jsfiddle and not html/cssfiddle. jsfiddle declares a doctype which puts browsers in quirks mode in case they got one (IE just gets totally confused and nothings works).

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Answer (score 0):

@Cobra; first close your `clear div` & instead of `clear:both` you can just write `overflow:hidden` in your parent div

```
<div style="float:left; overflow:hidden">
 <div style="float:left; height:200px"><!-- min-height hackfix --></div>
 CONTENT GOES HERE
</div>
```

**Edit:**

give `width:100%` to your child div.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Switching to your setup doesnt change a thing, though.

Comment: Looks like jsfiddle.net is set up for quirks mode, too. I want valid XHTML.